# Unable to recognize the postal code upon acount verification

Tags: heroku

I'm trying to Verify my account. and when I entered my credit card I got this error:

```
Unable to recognize the postal code. Please retry, or if the error persists contact support at https://help.heroku.com/.
```

I checked all my billing information (I'm located in Algeria North Africa) and tried again and the error persist.

Next I tried a random Florida address and a postal code. This time I got another error:

```
Unable to verify your card. Please try later or contact your financial institution for help.
```

Need to note that my card work just fine with every other website: Amazon, Google.. etc.

I tried another card and got the very same errors.

Comment: Did you solve it or not ?!!

Comment: No i use another service render.com

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue there, please make sure the billing address 1 is correct like the one used on the card holding bank that works for me.